# Mysql как отфильтровать по many to many по несоответствию

Tags: mysql, sql

схема данных следующая

```
Create table post (id, name)

Create table post_to_tag (post_id, tag_id)

Create table tag (id, name)
```

Необходимо написать запрос извлекающий все объекты A (посты), к которым привязаны объекты B (тэги) со значениями name 'тэг1' и 'тэг2' (одновременно, важно пересечение). Но при этом из выборки нужно убрать посты у которых есть теги со значениями name 'тэг3' и 'тэг4'

Пересечение по присутствующим тегам извлекают вот так:

```
SELECT p.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT all_tags.name) as i_tag from post as p

INNER JOIN post_to_tag AS ptg1 ON ptg.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tag AS t1 ON ptg1.tag_id = t1.id and t1.name = 'тэг1'

INNER JOIN post_to_tag AS ptg2 ON ptg.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tag AS t1 ON ptg2.tag_id = t2.id and t2.name = 'тэг2'

INNER JOIN post_to_tag AS all_ptg ON all_ptg.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tag AS all_tags ON all_git.tag_id = all_tags.id

GROUP BY (i.id)
```

Подскажите, как можно фильтровать по отсутствующим???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если совсем в лоб, то как нибудь так:

```
select p.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT all_tags.name) as i_tag
  from post as p
 INNER JOIN post_to_tag AS all_ptg ON all_ptg.post_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN tag AS all_tags ON all_git.tag_id = all_tags.id
 GROUP BY i.id
 HAVING sum(if(all_tags.name in('тэг1','тэг2'),1,0)) = 2
    AND sum(if(all_tags.name in('тэг3','тэг4'),1,0)) < 2
```

Здесь мы считаем количество тегов с нужными нам именами и проверяем все ли были. Но тут не ясно могут ли у вас у одного поста быть несколько одинаковых тегов (это собьет подсчет) и это может быть не эффективно в случае если индексы построены правильно, данных много а с тегами 1 и 2 мало и их было бы быстрее найти по индексу.

Или переделать запрос на IN/NOT IN:

```
select p.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT all_tags.name) as i_tag
  from post as p
 INNER JOIN post_to_tag AS all_ptg ON all_ptg.post_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN tag AS all_tags ON all_git.tag_id = all_tags.id
 WHERE p.id IN(
            select ptg.post_id
              from post_to_tag ptg
             INNER JOIN tag AS t1
                ON ptg.tag_id = t1.id and t1.name in('тэг1','тэг2')
             GROUP BY ptg.post_id
            HAVING count(distinct t1.name)=2
       )
   AND p.id NOT IN(
            select ptg.post_id
              from post_to_tag ptg
             INNER JOIN tag AS t1
                ON ptg.tag_id = t1.id and t1.name in('тэг3','тэг4')
             GROUP BY ptg.post_id
            HAVING count(distinct t1.name)=2
       )
 GROUP BY i.id
```

Так же можно комбинировать части от этих запросов между собой и с вашим изначальным вариантом, посмотреть при котором из них будет выше быстродействие.

Comment: Спасибо!
Если в лобовом решении в последнем условии исправить  "<2"  на "=0" , то будет работать так как и предполагалось.

Comment: @Roosh Тогда можете having с этим условием дописать к своему изначальному запросу, все таки там больше шансов на нормальную производительность